# Background / element easing. What is it called and how do you do it?

Tags: javascript, html

A lot of sites are using an easing function on single page sites. What is this function called. Is it jquery or just js!? Please point me in the right direction.
In the example you can see this functionality by clicking services. The page then automatically eases down to the element location.
In example 2: click the curtain at the bottom of the page to view functionality.

[Example](http://www.irontoiron.com/)
[Example 2](http://www.chipotle.com)

Comment: FYI the website you linked includes jquery; not sure if that's what it uses for that effect.

Answer (score 0):

they are using jquery,  in your example1 you can see using firebug that they are using jquery 1.6.2

there's also this [jquery plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) that you can use for such functionality

Answer (score 0):

Easing is actually, the “smoothing out” of an animation. Generally, an animation will simply start and stop very abruptly, which can look kind of ugly sometimes. Easing gives us a way to make our animations a bit smoother. This is done using jQuery, as referred in ur example as well. They most probably hav incorporated easing function withing their script. I can provide u a link where they hav explained this function at [this page](http://javascriptatoms.com/2011/03/how-to-use-the-jquery-easing-plugin-3/). However, u can use variety of scripts to obtain different effects by searching more in google.

Comment: Ahh!! So there are two different things going on with these examples. Example one is an internal link (an internal anchor tag) using easing. What is going on in example 2? It seems a whole new html document is under an html document